# mpich pass argument per CPU used

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, ubuntu-16.04, gnu-parallel

Given: 2 Ubuntu 16.04 machines with multiple CPU cores.

I want to execute multiple instances of `program fixed_arg arg2`on the machines, passing one file name per call as `arg2` to the program.
So far, working with xargs, this works on a single machine:

```
find . -iname "*.ext" -print | xargs -n1 -P12 program fixed_arg
```

(This will find all files with extension "ext" in the current directory (.), print one file per line (-print), and call xargs to call program 12 times in parallel (-P12) with only one argument `arg2`per call (-n1). Note the white space on the end of the whole command.)

I want to use multiple machines on which I installed the "mpich" package from the official Ubuntu 16.04 repositories.

I just do not know how to make mpiexec to run my program with only one argument on multiple machines.
I do know that mpiexec will accept a list of arguments, but my list will be in the range of 800 to 2000 files which so far has been to long for any program.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `find . -iname "*.ext" print | xargs -n800 -P1 | mpiexec -f hosts -np 6 program fixed_arg `
will start `program fixed_arg arg2, arg3, arg4, ...` on each node - not what I wanted.
I want `program fixed_arg arg2` started on node1, `program fixed_arg arg3` on node2 and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just selected wrong instrument (Or give us more details about your target program). **MPI** (mpich implementation, mpiexec and mpirun commands) **is not for starting unrelated programs** on multiple hosts, it is for starting one program with exactly same source code in the way, when program knows now many copies are there (up to 100 and more thousands) to do well-defined point-to-point and collective message passing between copies. It is instrument to parallel some scientific codes like computation over huge array which can't computed on single machine or even can't fit into its memory.

Better instrument for you can be **GNU parallel** (https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/); and if you have one or two machines or it is just several runs, it is easier to manually split your file list in two parts, and run two `parallel` or `xargs` on every machine (by hand or with `ssh` using authorized_keys). I'll assume that all files are accessible from both machines at the same path (NFS share or something like; no magic tool like mpi or gnu parallel will forward files for you, but batch some modern batch processing system may):

```
find . -iname "*.ext" -print > list
l=$(wc -l < list) 
sp=$((l/2))
split -l $sp list 
cat xaa | xargs -n1 -P12 program fixed_arg &
cat xab | ssh SECOND_HOST xargs -n1 -P12 program fixed_arg & 
wait
```

Or just learn about multi-host usage of GNU `parallel`: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

> `-S @hostgroup` Distribute jobs to remote computers. The jobs will be run on a list of remote computers. GNU parallel will determine the number of CPU cores on the remote computers and run the number of jobs as specified by -j.
>
> EXAMPLE: Using remote computers

It also has a magic of sending files to remote machine with `--transferfile filename` option if you have no shared FS between two ubuntus.

Comment: You are completely right, I figured that parallel is more appropriate for this task. I got it working in the meantime.

I followed this guide to set up MPICH and the NFS share:
https://www-users.cs.york.ac.uk/~mjf/pi_cluster/src/Building_a_simple_Beowulf_cluster.html

Running GNU parallel works like a charm:
`find . -iname "*.ext" -print | parallel -S host1 -S host2 --eta program fixedarg {}`
will result in my files being processed on both machines!

Comment: @user7677771, if your question is answered, can I retag it with gnu-parallel and can you mark my answer as correct as clicking "v"-shaped button near voting buttons left from it?

Comment: yes, please retag to parallel and thank you for yor time :). I am not sure why my question was downvoted, what is wrong with it?